# Razor like engine in the Spring MVC world that implements Editor/Display templates

Tags: spring-mvc, razor, partial-views, mvc-editor-templates

I am moving from ASP.Net MVC to Java Spring MVC.  There where two features that I found very powerful and useful in ASP.Net MVC's Razor which will be of great value in the Java Spring MVC world:

1. Partial Views
2. Editor/Display templates

Does this concept exist in any of the many java based rendering engines?  If so, which ones and what is the feature called?

Comment: Partial Views look pretty similar to JSP Tag Files.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by editor/display templates, but there are several templating engines available for Java servlets.  Thymeleaf has become one of my favorites.  If it's more along the lines of dynamically generated forms based on your model objects, you could create a custom JSP tag to do such a thing.  It wouldn't be to hard to use reflections to pull in all the available getters/setters and build the appropriate display/edit output.